# Filtering out based on count using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am using Dataflow and Apache Beam to process a dataset and store the result in a headerless csv file with two columns, something like this:

```
A1,a
A2,a
A3,b
A4,a
A5,c
...
```

I want to filter out certain entries based on the following two conditions:

1- In the second column, if the number of occurrences of a certain value is less than `N`, then remove all such rows. For instance if `N=10` and `c` only appears 7 times, then I want all those rows to be filtered out.

2- In the second column, if the number of occurrences of a certain value is more than `M`, then only keep `M` many of such rows and filter out the rest. For instance if `M=1000` and `a` appears 1200 times, then I want 200 of such entries to be filtered out, and the other 1000 cases to be stored in the csv file.

In other words, I want to make sure all elements of the second columns appear more than `N` and less than `M` many times.

My question is whether this is possible by using some filter in Beam? Or should it be done as a post-process step once the csv file is created and saved?

Comment: In case if N=10 and M=100 and you, for example, "c" appears: a) 99, b) 100 and c) 101 times. How many output elements it's expected to be for every case?

Comment: Let's say for instance, if c is 99 or 100, all cases should be included. When c is 101, one case should be excluded, while the other 100 case should be included in the csv file  (does not matter how they are chosen).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beam.Filter` to filter out all the second column values that matches your range's lower bound condition into a PCollection.
Then correlate that PCollection (as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs)) with your original PCollection to filter out all the lines that need to be excluded.
As for the upperbound, since you want to keep any upperbound amount of elements instead of excluding them completely, you should do some post processing or come up with some combine transforms to do that.

An example with Python SDK using word count.

```
class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):

def __init__(self, file_pattern):
    self._file_pattern = file_pattern

def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (pcoll.pipeline
            | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)
            | beam.FlatMap(lambda line: re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)))

p = beam.Pipeline()
words = (p 
     | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText('gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')
     | "lower" >> beam.Map(lambda word: word.lower()))
import random
# Assume this is the data PCollection you want to do filter on.
data = words | beam.Map(lambda word: (word, random.randint(1, 101)))
counts = (words 
      | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())
words_with_counts_bigger_than_100 = counts | beam.Filter(lambda count: count[1] > 100) | beam.Map(lambda count: count[0])
```

Now you get a pcollection like [image: this]

```
def cross_join(left, rights):
    for x in rights:
        if left[0] == x:
           yield (left, x)
data_with_word_counts_bigger_than_100 = data | beam.FlatMap(cross_join, rights=beam.pvalue.AsIter(words_with_counts_bigger_than_100))
```

Now you filtered out elements below lowerbound from the data set and get [image: this]

Note the `66` from `('king', 66)` is the fake random data I put in.

To debug with such visualizations, you can use interactive beam. You can setup your own notebook runtime following [instructions](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive#interactive-beam); Or you can use hosted solutions provided by [Google Dataflow Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/interactive-pipeline-development).